# OpenGL VBOs: Drawing a sphere

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, vbo

I'm having some trouble drawing out a sphere.

```
std::vector<GLfloat> ballVerts;

for(int i = 0; i <= 40; i++)
{
    double lat0 = M_PI * (-0.5 + (double) (i - 1) / 40);
    double z0  = sin(lat0);
    double zr0 =  cos(lat0);

    double lat1 = M_PI * (-0.5 + (double) i / 40);
    double z1 = sin(lat1);
    double zr1 = cos(lat1);

    for(int j = 0; j <= 40; j++)
    {
        double lng = 2 * M_PI * (double) (j - 1) / 40;
        double x = cos(lng);
        double y = sin(lng);

        ballVerts.push_back(x * zr0); //X
        ballVerts.push_back(y * zr0); //Y
        ballVerts.push_back(z0);      //Z

        ballVerts.push_back(0.0f); 
        ballVerts.push_back(1.0f); 
        ballVerts.push_back(0.0f); 
        ballVerts.push_back(1.0f); //R,G,B,A

        ballVerts.push_back(x * zr1); //X
        ballVerts.push_back(y * zr1); //Y
        ballVerts.push_back(z1);      //Z

        ballVerts.push_back(0.0f); 
        ballVerts.push_back(1.0f); 
        ballVerts.push_back(0.0f); 
        ballVerts.push_back(1.0f); //R,G,B,A
    }
}

glGenBuffers(1, &ballVbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, ballVbo);

GLuint sphereSize = 3200*7*4; //3200 vertixes * 7 floats
glBufferData(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY,sphereSize, &ballVerts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);



/*
    Draw a ball
*/
glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, ballVbo);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 7*4, 0);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 7*4, (void*)(3*4));

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 3200);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

The code for generating the sphere works fine in immediate mode, but when I put it in a VBO I keep getting an access violation exception from glDrawArrays. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
glBufferData(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY,sphereSize, &ballVerts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

`ballVerts` is *not* an array. It is a `std::vector`. Taking the address of a `std::vector` doesn't get the address of the array contained *within* the `vector`. You need to use `&ballVerts[0]`;

Comment: If you have access to C++11, you could also std::vector's .data() method.  This, I believe, avoids the issue of using the address operator on an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

better pre-resize vector and use iterator to sweep through it
something like this:

```
 std::vector <GLfloat> vertices;
 vertices.resize(count * 3);
 ...
 std::vector <GLfloat>::iterator v = vertices.begin();

 for( U32 r = 0; r < m_prec/2; ++r ) //широта
    {
        float const theta1 = -F_PI_BY_TWO + pi2p * r;
        float const theta2 = theta1 +  pi2p;

        for( U32 s = 0; s < m_prec; ++s ) //долгота
        {
            float const theta3 =  s * pi2p;     

            float ex = cosf(theta3) *cosf(theta2);
            float ey = sinf(theta2);
            float ez = sinf(theta3) * cosf(theta2);
            *v++ = m_x + m_radius * ex;
            *v++ = m_y + m_radius * ey;
            *v++ = m_z + m_radius * ez;
```

etc.

::glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0 , &vertices[0]);

would work

Comment: is it really working? why i try the code in intermediate mode, it just give me a circle? Also when i try to use glBegin(GL_Points) instead, it just give me points which make a circle..